# How long (maximum characters) is an LDAP distinguished name?

Tags: ldap

Is there a maximum length to DN's? If I want to store them in a database table, what would I set the length to?

Comment: I searched stackoverflow before I posted, I couldn't find anything... I guess I couldn't think of another way to phrase what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no defined maximum length of a distinguished name, or of an attribute value, in an LDAP-compliant server, though certainly there would be a practical limit because resources are finite. Non-compliant servers are whatever their designers build, of course.

Comment: I searched the specification before posting, I couldn't find a limit there. But I wasn't sure.

Comment: @TerryGardner, could you refer to an authoritative source confirming that DNs are not intended to be limited in length?. I've been unable to find such a confirmation in standards like X.520 or RFC 5280.

Answer (score 4):

I think the maximum length which is allowed is 255 characters.

Check [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> **Name Length Limitations for LDAP Simple Bind Operations**
>
> During binds to the directory, simple LDAP bind operations limit the
>   distinguished name (also known as DN) of the user to 255 total
>   characters. If you attempt a simple LDAP bind with more than 255
>   characters, you might experience authentication errors

Comment: That page applies to Active Directory only.

Comment: And only if doing simple bind.  Same doc states if you use secure bind you won't hit that limit.